# cant login MySQL through terminal

Tags: mysql

Im a macbook user.
I try to access mySQL through the terminal, but after entering the password, I receive an error message. Like this

```
Pasindu@Pasidus-Air ~ % mysql -h localhost -u root -p 
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

How to fix that problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you're using unix domain sockets you cannot use `-h` flag.
Use the following if socket path is default:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

If path is not default just pass `-S` flag.

```
mysql -u root -p -S /var/run/mysqld/mysql.sock
```